# Como agrupar JSONs por dados?

Tags: javascript, json

Necessito transformar dados que viriam na seguinte estrutura:

```
[
    {id_fornecedor: '100', id_pedido: '9000', id_produto: '4455', quantidade: '5' },
    {id_fornecedor: '100', id_pedido: '9000', id_produto: '4456', quantidade: '2' },
    {id_fornecedor: '100', id_pedido: '9001', id_produto: '4457', quantidade: '3' }
]
```

Na seguinte estrutura:

```
[
    { id_fornecedor: '100', 
      pedidos: [ 
          { 
            id_pedido: '9000', 
            itens: [ 
                      {id_produto: '4455', quantidade: '5'}, 
                      {id_produto: '4456', quantidade: '2'} 
                   ]
          }, 
          {
             id_pedido: '9001', 
             itens: [ 
                      {id_produto: '4457', quantidade: '3'} 
                    ] 
          } 
       ]
    }
]
```

Sendo que nem `id_fornecedor` e nem `id_pedido` virão necessariamente ordenados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não é exatamente uma questão trivial, a resposta ficou basicamente um "faça para mim", mas não tem o que ser explicado, é basicamente um monte de `if` e `else`.

```js
const dados = [{ id_fornecedor: '100', id_pedido: '9000', id_produto: '4455', quantidade: '5' }, { id_fornecedor: '100', id_pedido: '9000', id_produto: '4456', quantidade: '2' }, { id_fornecedor: '100', id_pedido: '9001', id_produto: '4457', quantidade: '3' }]

const dados_formatados = dados.reduce((acc, px) => {
    const fornecedor = acc.find(py => py.id_fornecedor === px.id_fornecedor)
    if (fornecedor) {
        const pedido = fornecedor.pedidos.find(pz => pz.id_pedido === px.id_pedido)
        if (pedido) {
            pedido.itens.push({
                id_produto: px.id_produto,
                quantidade: px.quantidade
            })
        } else {
            fornecedor.pedidos.push({
                id_pedido: px.id_pedido,
                itens: [{
                    id_produto: px.id_produto,
                    quantidade: px.quantidade
                }]
            })
        }
    } else {
        acc.push({
            id_fornecedor: px.id_fornecedor,
            pedidos: [{
                id_pedido: px.id_pedido,
                itens: [{
                    id_produto: px.id_produto,
                    quantidade: px.quantidade
                }]
            }]
        })
    }
    return acc
}, [])

console.log(dados_formatados)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, era isso mesmo. Não fui muito claro na pergunta, estava buscando uma solução nativa, imaginei que seria algo relacionado com o .reduce() e estava certo

Answer (score 0):

Se o JSON transformado não precisar ser exatamente igual a esse, você pode usar a função [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/#groupBy) do [lodash](https://lodash.com):

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

const itens = [
    {id_fornecedor: '100', id_pedido: '9000', id_produto: '4455', quantidade: '5' },
    {id_fornecedor: '100', id_pedido: '9000', id_produto: '4456', quantidade: '2' },
    {id_fornecedor: '100', id_pedido: '9001', id_produto: '4457', quantidade: '3' }
];

const itensAgrupados = _.groupBy(itens, 'id_fornecedor');

console.log(itensAgrupados);
```

O resultado será:

```js
{
    "100": [{
        "id_fornecedor": "100",
        "id_pedido": "9000",
        "id_produto": "4455",
        "quantidade": "5"
    }, {
        "id_fornecedor": "100",
        "id_pedido": "9000",
        "id_produto": "4456",
        "quantidade": "2"
    }, {
        "id_fornecedor": "100",
        "id_pedido": "9001",
        "id_produto": "4457",
        "quantidade": "3"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Anotado! Para agora busco uma solução nativa, mas com certeza essa não deixa de estar correta :)